# Short story collection with the story, "Dead Language Teacher" in it

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book

There was an old anthology of horror/sci-fi stories that I read in about 1975, but the paperback was older.  I think it was a *Twilight Zone*, with Rod Serling maybe on the back cover. But it was not a collection of the television series scripts.  I think maybe Serling was just used on the back cover to promote sales.  It had a story called, "Dead Language Teacher."  Which was about a bad boy in school who was troublesome to the Latin teacher, I think, it was.

Answer (score 7):

I can’t read the entire story, but could the story be *Dead Language Master* by Joan Aiken?

> Mr Fletcher taught us Latin. He was the shape of a domino. No, that’s wrong, because he wasn’t square; he looked as though he had been cut out of a domino. He had shape but no depth, you felt as though he could have slipped through the crack at the hinge of a door if he’d gone sideways.

This story has been in [many sci-fi/horror anthologies](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?847863), the first of which was published in 1965.

Comment: FWIW, [*The Green Flash and Other Tales of Horror, Suspense, and Fantasy*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2980959-the-green-flash-and-other-tales-of-horror-suspense-and-fantasy) has both "Dead Language Master" and "Marmalade Wine", the latter of which was made into a Rod Serling *Night Gallery* episode. I haven't seen a copy of the cover mentioning that, but it could explain the connection.